# Update another UI element when propertychanged Xaml

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, attachedbehaviors

I want to know if it's possible to update another UI element when propertychanged gets invoked.

Here's an example:

```
public string TestString 
{
    get { return testString; }
    set
    {
        testString = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("TestString");
    }
}

public TestClass TestClassInstance { get; set; }
```

Suppose my test class has a method called Update. How do I set it so that Update gets called when TestString property has changed in Xaml? I know I could always attach the method to the eventhandler but I wanted to know if I could do it in Xaml. Maybe using Behaviours or something like that. 
Can you tell me if this is possible and if so can you help lead me in the right direction?

Comment: You can use Element Binding. refer the example of textbox an textbloack.  <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" Width="200" Height="25"/>
        <TextBlock  Width="200" Height="25" Text="{Binding ElementName=txtBox,Path=Text,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

Comment: @Ganesh Yes I know you can link an element of another UI element to another one. I mean I want to call an update method in TestClassInstance when TextBox has been changed. How do I do that?

Comment: Just update it in code.  This ain't magic, and nothing in xaml should "know" that your TestClassInstance should have its Update method called when TestString is changed.

Comment: @Will Yes I know it's not magic. I wanted to know if it would be possible to do something like it with an Attached Behaviour. I'm a bit rusty with WPF and was wondering if I had to do this in the model/Viewmodel or if it would be possible to do it with a behaviour and set it through xaml.

Comment: Possibly.  But you'd have to write it.  Nothing exists in the framework that runs method X in property Y when property Z is updated :/

Comment: @Will Yes I know I would have to write it. That's why at the end of the question I asked if someone could lead me in the right direction. I guess my question wasn't clear. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [Behaviours](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn269476.aspx)

```
<!-- This collection element might exist if you have already added other behaviors. -->
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger SourceName="textBox" EventName="TextChanged">
        <ic:CallMethodAction MethodName="Update" TargetObject="{Binding TestClassInstance}">
        </ic:CallMethodAction>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>

<Textbox x:Name="textBox" Content="{Binding TestString, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

But I am not sure if you can catch up changes from code via this method. If your Update Method is a command, you should use `InvokeActionCommand` instead.

```
<cmd:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TestClassInstance.Update}"/>
```

But why would you want to put this into XAML? Is it a Behavior very specific to a certain view or application type?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :). It works for the most part but how do I make it work for a user control? Say I have a user control that contains a listbox and I want to invoke a command based on the selection being changed in the user control? How do I get that information in the main view?

Ex: 

<i:EventTrigger SourceObject="{Binding UserControl}" EventName="SelectionChanged">
...

Comment: Nvm. I just added a SelectionChanged EventHandler to my usercontrol and invoked it whenever my listbox selectionchanged.